# Realtime Inference of Stateful Variable-Length Time Series LSTM - Getting around Sequence Length vs Inference Frequency Tradeoff

Tags: neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, data-preprocessing, time-series, real-time

I am trying to train a neural net for low-latency signal filtering; I've been recommended to use a stateful LSTM architecture for this task, however, having corrected some , it seems to me that trying to balance the realtime nature with the need to give the network sequential data and it feels like there isn't a possible way to do this. But I can't be the first one to have tried using an LSTM on realtime input, so it would be good to know if there is a way

The input signal for this is a simple continuous 1D time series - this will be coming from an EEG in the end, but, I think the principles apply to anything, so you can imagine it as audio, voltage from an antenna, what ever is easiest to visualise -  currently I am just training it on synthetic data of relatively pure sinusoids. The model takes a sequence of the N most recent  values, and then needs to learn to predict the (scalar) vvalue of the filtered signal for the current timestep. This picture gives some illustration - the network should predict the orange given the blue:

[image: Filtering signal]

We can neglect computation time for the moment; what concerns me is how the sequence length of the inference data will be tied to the input sample rate of the signal, and if this backs us into a corner where we either give the model very little context, or are stuck running inference on it only every so often.

Claude and Copilot previously gave me some quite incorrect advice about how stateful LSTMs work with relation to the feeding in of data, so I've had to correct my understanding. To check if that's correct before I go any further, as far a I know:

- The different "samples" within a batch are processed in parallel - in the sense that they're not seen as temporally related. (I say "samples" because this nomenclature could be confusing when to me, samples are subsequent timesteps in the signal coming off my amplifier, but this means each one of the BatchLength sets of data within a batch). So as these samples are not processed as if they related to eahc other serially, they could well be multiple channels coming from different sensors, for example; if you were trying to train the model to predict a stock market crash, each sample could be a different share price - there's relation, but they're not the same data series. Therefore, using these samples within the batch would increase the amount of data the network sees, and using similar signals helps it learn similar patterns - but fundamentally the LSTM treats each of these signals independently, and non-sequentially.
- For a stateful LSTM, the state is retained across batches for sample at the same index within that batch; so for a given sample, if we concatenate the data across batches, these will stitch together into the full signal.

This is a very rough picture:

[image: batches]

Each sample in the batch is outlined in yellow; each batch in blue. My understanding is that, in essence, the orange windows of the sequence, need to follow each other batch-to-batch, for the model's inputs to be valid.

This therefore means that if each batch has to be sequential, and follow from the last in a non-overlapping way, without repeating data that have already been seen. then in essence the sequence length and the signal sample rate will determine how often we can run inference on the model. This then leads us to a tradeoff - if we want to give the model a nice long sequence of say a second, so that it can learn the dependencies between the data within the batch, then we can only run inference once every second, as we have to wait for a full batch of new data to come in from the sensor. If we sent in the most recentsamples and then almost a second of data along the timesteps axis, then this would break the assumptions of the (stateful) LSTM model - that each data point in the timestep axis came after the last. Meanwhile, if we want to run inference 64 times a second (to get suitable latency for the downstream pipeline), then our sequence length that the model will see before gradients are updated is limited by how many new samples we can collect in that time - in my case, just 8, which is not much information at all to learn from directly. So we can feed the model on a good amount of data, or run it rapidly in production - but not both.

At least not directly. What I'm wondering is if there is a common way around this. I was previously using sliding windows, and assumed this would be a suitable way to manage a situation like this - but as mentioned, discovered that the information I had been given about structuring these across time was not correct, and thus my method of feeding data was invalid. I see a few ways one could exploit the architecture to perform sliding windows - *but it seems that at a base level, if each batch has to contain data that came after the last, I haven't thought of any way yet that gets us away from this tradeoff of having a large enough sequence length vs running regular inference on it.*

So far, I haven't managed to come up with a way to get around that for a stateful LSTM. The only real potential I have thought of that might work would be to use a stateless layer first to process a long window into the past, and then have subsequent layers be stateful, so that it would be okay to feed in overlapping data ot the first layer, and then the subsequent layers would be working in a latent space, and so what they see might possibly be deemed to be sequential in that space, even if there's some overlap.

So, are there any common workarounds for this scenario? Is it possible to give the model a relatively long context such that it can pick out data that ocurred some time ago, whilst also being able to run inference on the model faster than it takes to obtain a full length of that data? Is there a way to perform sliding windows on a stateful LSTM that makes sense and doesn't break the causal relations between batches?

Thanks a lot